# I'm having problems with the OpenWeather API + geolocation

Tags: javascript, geolocation, weather-api

This is my first time working with an API. It will be part of a bigger practice project, but I'm a bit stuck.
First, I want my code to geolocate the user, get the altitude and longitude, than using that make a call to the OpenWeather API and console log the temperature, humidity and the description. My problem seems to be that my link is not working... can anyone help me explain what am I doing wrong? (The Api key is deleted here)

```
 /*Geolocation*/

let latUser = []
let lonUser = []


const errorCallback = (error) => {console.error(error)}
const successCallback = (position) => {
    latUser.push(position.coords.latitude)
    lonUser.push(position.coords.longitude)}

navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(successCallback, errorCallback) 

/*Weather*/

let weather = {
    "apiKey": "xxx",
    fetchWeather: function () {
        fetch("api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=" + latUser[0] + "&lon=" + lonUser[0] +
         "&appid=" + this.apiKey
        ).then((response) => response.json())
        .then((data) => this.displayWeather(data))
    },
    displayWeather: function(data){
        const { temp, humidity } = data.main
        const { description } = data.weather
        console.log (temp, humidity, description)
    }
}
```

Comment: You are probably not handing the asynchronous aspect of geolocation correctly here (although hard to tell, because you have only shown us your `weather` object, but not where you are actually calling its `fetchWeather` method.)

Comment: you will need to put a https:// before your url - otherwise the browser will think its a relative URL

Comment: Sorry! I just want to call it in the console for now. It seems like adding https://  before the url fixed it, thank you so much! My bad.